# Add a "Check All/Uncheck All" checkbox for a group of Tasks?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I made an installer with 4 task-groups, and each group has like 30-40 checkeable tasks, it's a little bit insane to uncheck all the tasks manually, and I don't want to set a `Component` because the intention is give free choice to select/check/uncheck whatever tasks you want to perform in the installer, I think a `Component` could be a bad approach for this installer.

Then, I would like to know if I could add a checkbox titled "**Check all**" at the top of each tasks-group that will check or uncheck all the tasks inside that tasks-gruop, and that checkbox alternates the name to "**Uncheck all**" to do the opposite thing.

How I could do this?, is necessary to use pascal code?

Comment: Would you mind if they would be without a group description and would be indented ? I'm thinking of building the real task hierarchy ([`an example`](http://pastebin.com/BxBHeW4U)).

Comment: @TLama thanks for your help, I would like to keep the group descriptions because is the unique "separator", as I said the installer its full of tasks (+100) then without group descriptions it could be insane to navigate through them without that necessary information and separator. If you mean the group description parameter in the source code then really doesns't matter in case that I could still add my group descriptions in the UI. About the indentantion, what thing you mean? indentation in the source or in the resulting UI? I wonder that I could keep my current UI size,beacuse is big.thanks

Comment: With that indentantion I mean that if you have a task hierarchy, children has an indent (the output of a real task hierarchy you can see if you run the script I posted in the linked pastebin). But with a real task hierarchy you would lose group descriptions, which you do not want to. On the other hand, such hierarchy was designed just for this purpose. Hm, I can think of many ways, but each would need to use indexed access from code, which is then difficult to maintain.

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed the linked url!, yes, that result is fantastic!, i don't have problems with it and with indentation is more readable, please feel free to post an answer to mark it as the accepted one, thanks again! just would be great if you could link the official documentation that explains that hierarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is building a task hierarchy, which can be done by writing *paths* built from the [`Name`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=Name) parameters of your task entries separated by `\`, or `/` chars. This is quite hidden in the [`Name`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=Name) parameter documentation:

> The total number of \ or / characters in the name of the task is
>   called the level of the task. Any task with a level of 1 or more is a
>   child task. The task listed before the child task with a level of 1
>   less than the child task, is the parent task. Other tasks with the
>   same parent task as the child task are sibling tasks.

For example, to make a hierarchy of a parent, child and subchild you could write:

```
[Tasks]
Name: parent; Description: "Parent task"; Flags: unchecked
Name: parent\child; Description: "Child task"; Flags: unchecked
Name: parent\child\subchild; Description: "Subchild task"; Flags: unchecked
```

And the tasks page will produce this:

[image]

Tasks built in hierarchy by default inherit check states (unless you specify [`dontinheritcheck`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=dontinheritcheck) flag for your child task entries), so for your overall aim you may write something like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Tasks]
Name: group1; Description: "Check/uncheck all"; GroupDescription: "1. Group description"; Flags: unchecked
Name: group1\task1; Description: "1. Task"; Flags: unchecked
Name: group1\task2; Description: "2. Task"; Flags: unchecked
Name: group1\task3; Description: "3. Task"; Flags: unchecked

Name: group2; Description: "Check/uncheck all"; GroupDescription: "2. Group description"; Flags: unchecked
Name: group2\task1; Description: "1. Task"; Flags: unchecked
Name: group2\task2; Description: "2. Task"; Flags: unchecked
Name: group2\task3; Description: "3. Task"; Flags: unchecked
```

And the tasks page will produce this:

[image]